# URLEncodedUtils.parse returns the URL itself as first entry. What im doing wrong?

Tags: java

I try to get the query params of an redirectUri. So I tried out the URLEncodedUtils helper.

```
List<NameValuePair> parse = URLEncodedUtils.parse(redirectedTo, Charset.defaultCharset());
```

It works fine, but as result of.

```
https://my.redirect.de/foo?code=123&state=123
```

I got a List

```
[{name:https://my.redirect.de/foo?code, value: 123}, {name:state, value:123}]
```

This is suboptimal. What im doing wrong? When I first have to split the params from the URL the helperclass isnt helpful that much. Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation it is stated *Returns a list of NameValuePairs as parsed from the given string using the given character encoding. By convention, '&' and ';' are accepted as parameter separators.*

So the questionmark is not a separator, hence no distinction is made as to the URL part.

I don't know in what context you are using this, but generally in Java there are methods to retrieve the querystring, which you can then pass to your method.

What I would do:

```
URL url = new URL("https://my.redirect.de/foo?code=123&state=123");
String queryString = url.getQuery();
List<NameValuePair> parse = URLEncodedUtils.parse(queryString, Charset.defaultCharset());
```